# Displaying Related Attributes when i select a Category from the dropdown list?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, magento-1.7

I want to display the Attributes based on selection from the dropdown list.For this i wrote some code it is working fine in local(out side the Magento),Now i want to work it out in side the magento....I am using Magento CE 1.7

this is my code (out side magento code)

Local code :-

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <select id="xyz">
        <option value="Men">Men</option>
        <option value="Women">Women</option>
        <option value="Kids">Kids</option>
        <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
        <option value="Books">Books</option>
    </select>
  <div id="Men" class="group">
    Color<input id="color" name="color" type="text">
    Size<input id="size" name="size" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="Women" class="group">
    Size<input id="size" name="size" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="Kids" class="group">
    Color<input id="color" name="color" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="Furniture" class="group">
    Color<input id="color" name="color" type="text">
    Size<input id="size" name="size" type="text">
    Finishing<input id="finishing" name="finishing">
  </div>
  <div id="Books" class="group">
    ISBN<input id="isbn" name="isbn" type="text">
  </div>
  </body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
        $('#Men').show();
        $('#xyz').change(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        })
         });
    </script>
    </script>
</html>
```

Yeah Now i want to apply same thing in magento Dropdown Categories for this i wrote this code But its not working Why ? Anything wrong i did ?

Magento Code:-

```
  <tr>
<td class="tdpadfirst">
   <label for="category" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Product Category') ?>:</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td class="tdpadsec">
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <select id="xyz" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category">
        <option value="">--Select Categories--</option>
        <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
        <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
        <element onclick="<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>">
        <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_category->getId() ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

```
    <div id="Mens" class="group">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="size" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Size') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="size" class="required-entry widthinput" name="size" id="size" value="<?php echo $size ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: 10,20) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="seller_colour" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Color') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="seller_colour" class="required-entry widthinput" name="seller_colour" id="seller_colour" value="<?php echo $seller_colour ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: White,Black) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
</div>
<div id="Womens" class="group">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="size" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Size') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="size" class="required-entry widthinput" name="size" id="size" value="<?php echo $size ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: 10,20) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
</div>
<div id="Kids" class="group">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="seller_colour" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Color') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="seller_colour" class="required-entry widthinput" name="seller_colour" id="seller_colour" value="<?php echo $seller_colour ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: White,Black) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
</div>
<div id="furniture" class="group">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="seller_colour" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Color') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="seller_colour" class="required-entry widthinput" name="seller_colour" id="seller_colour" value="<?php echo $seller_colour ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: White,Black) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
</div>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#Mens').show();
    $('#category').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    });
</script>
</script>
```

Here i am Using Magento CE 1.7

any Ideas ?

Comment: In my Magento site i have only 4 categories those are  Mens,Womens,Kids,Furniture   ......any one can help me please its very importent for me ....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

seems your layout is clumsy,

```
<div id="Kids" class="group">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdpadfirst">
        <label for="seller_colour" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Color') ?> :</label><span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="tdpadsec">
        <input type="seller_colour" class="required-entry widthinput" name="seller_colour" id="seller_colour" value="<?php echo $seller_colour ?>"/>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('For multiple values separate with , (Example: White,Black) ') ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
</div>
```

Im not sure how could you place `<tr>` inside a `<div>` tag?, please re organize them in div structure

```
<table>
<tr><td>

your category divs

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```